# How to build library from header and source files which located in different folders?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following struct:

```
some_folder:
--libs:
  --headers: 
    --my_lib.h
    --CMakeLists.txt
  --sources: 
    --my_lib.cpp
    --CMakeLists.txt
  --CMakeLists.txt
--main.cpp
--CMakeLists.txt
```

some_folder/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(lesson_03)

add_subdirectory(libs)
add_executable(lesson_03 main.cpp)
```

But what should the other CMakeLists.txt files contain?

Comment: Why do you place a `CMakeLists.txt` file in every directory?

Comment: Please complete you [mre] by showing the content of all CMakeLists.txt files.

Comment: Do you want to use my_lib in the shape of a code file and a header file (i.e. only the final result of all mentioned files is the lib you mention in the title) or do you want to create a lib of them and us them that way? What kind of lib? Static, dynamic, cmake-pseudo, ...

Answer (score 1):

No need for all the nested CMakeLists, just create a library target in the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(my_lib STATIC libs/sources/my_lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(my_lib PUBLIC libs/headers)
```

and link your main executable to it:

```
target_link_libraries(lesson_03 PUBLIC my_lib)
```

The `target_link_libraries` will also propagate the include directory to `lesson_03` so you do not need to do anything special for it.